# Disabling the Sing In popup of OpenSearch

Tags: security, opensearch

I've installed OpenSearch 2.11.1 locally on my PC, configured self-signed SSL certificate for secure connection, and was able to access OpenSearch on https://localhost:9200, providing the login:admin password:admin credentials.
Now I want to disable this Sign In feature, but still leave the secure connection.

I tried adding the "*plugins.security.disabled: true*" in the application.yml file , but this disables all security for my cluster, forcing me to access Open Search via http.
I tried to modify the OpenSearch/config/opensearch-security/config.yml , and configured the **clientcert_auth_domain** by setting **http_enabled: true** and **transport_enabled: true** , and setting to false all other **http_enabled** and **transport_enabled** from **authc**, but I still get the Sign In page :

```
clientcert_auth_domain:
        description: "Authenticate via SSL client certificates"
        http_enabled: true
        transport_enabled: true
        order: 2
        http_authenticator:
          type: clientcert
          config:
            username_attribute: cn #optional, if omitted DN becomes username
          challenge: false
        authentication_backend:
          type: noop
```

I wonder if this would actually be possible, and I need some help from whom who knows more than me about this

Comment: Found a potential solution for this, using the Anonymous User: in the config.yml file, set "anonymous_auth_enabled: true", in the authc block, set "transport_enabled: false" and "transport_enabled: false" for all, add "anonymous_users_role:
  reserved: true"
in the config.yml file
use the securityadmin.bat tool: "OpenSearch\plugins\opensearch-security\tools>securityadmin.bat -cd ../../../config/opensearch-security/ -icl -nhnv -cacert ../../../config/root-ca.pem \ -cert ../../../config/node.crt \ -key ../../../config/node.key" to apply the changes.
Note : modify configs per yr needs.